Oracle SQL gives ORA-01790 without UNION, and a workaround works strangely. Why?
We have an Oracle view "view1", which SQL is like this:
select ...,
       nvl(iac.indirect_attri_cost, 0) + nvl(pc.premises_cost, 0) + nvl(cc.central_cost, 0) total_cost
from   (select ..., cc.CENTRAL_COST 
        from   .. cc, .. rl
        where  ...) cc
full   outer join (select ...) iac
on     ...
full   outer join (select ...) pc
on     ...
left   join ... dept
on     ...

Note the CENTRAL_COST field we shown.
It works fine.
But our another view, "view2", uses this view1, and it crashes with "ORA-01790 expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression":
select * from view1

Yes, just like that.
We realized that something wrong in datatypes, ok, then we found a workaround done in View1, which is to wrap the column with TO_CHAR, and TO_NUMBER it later (for calculation purpose):
select ...,
       nvl(iac.indirect_attri_cost, 0) + nvl(pc.premises_cost, 0) + nvl(TO_NUMBER(cc.central_cost), 0) total_cost
from   (select ..., TO_CHAR(cc.CENTRAL_COST)
        from   .. cc, .. rl
        where  ...) cc
full   outer join (select ...) iac
on     ...
full   outer join (select ...) pc
on     ...
left   join ... dept
on     ...

This modified view1 works fine in view2.But we do not understand what's wrong and how it is solved!
Even further, we found that applying different Optimization goal in view1 would bypass that error. This even confused us more!
Could anyone gives some insight? Thanks much.

Sounds like a bug. If you have a support contract you can look on Oracle Support for known bugs matching your Oracle version and patch level, and what you are doing; or raise a service request.

Hard to tell with incomplete code, but ORA-01790 is raised mostly as a datatype problem when there is either UNION / UNION ALL or UNPIVOT in the query. Both requires the same coresponding datatypes. Do you have Union or Unpivot in the code raising this error?

No any union/union all in the code - the core part I have shown. The hidden ones are just table/column names.
Some DBA in our team says that Oracle may internally rewrite the SQL in a form with UNION inside and that causes the error -- but even it happens, it should not bring data type issues... :(

What about UNPIVOT ???

We dont have unpivot in the query. Just joins.

From Oracle blog:     link
"Before Oracle Database 11g Release 1, all ANSI full outerjoins were converted into a UNION ALL query with two branches, where one branch contained a left outerjoined lateral view and the other branch contained a NOT EXISTS subquery. A native support for hash full outerjoin was introduced in Oracle Database 11g Release 1 to overcome this problem. When the native full outer join, cannot be used, Oracle reverts to the pre-11gR1 strategy)"
You are probably using Oracle version higher the 11gR1, so try to check your data again and try to find out if there is something that could cause Oracle to decide that full outer join cannot be used. Read the explain plans of different queries. This would explain the "anomaly" described in your question. The original plan should be one that is converted to use Union instead of outer join and the plan that has a different optimization goal applyed to, used outer join (no Union - no issue). Additionaly, your intervention with To_Char() / To_Number() that works fine is the intervention that is used to resolve the Union datatype issue when adjusting unioned data. Since that worked fine - it could be because Union was used instead of outer join. If that is the case then it should be detected and analyzed comparing the explaine plans.
The error is raised when there are different datatype groups using an operator such as UNION , UNPIVOT, INTERSECT, or EXCEPT  to run a compound query.

We use 19c.
We tried show plan. But for those failed cases, my tool does not even show the plan... Cannot see if Oracle choose Union or not .. but yes, now I tend to believe that the Oracle does transform the SQL in certain cases, either for data or whatever reasons, that causes the crash.
